# CSS class not being applied to input element on asynchronous call back

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-7

I am using the following CSS class to hide a textbox in an `asp:UpdatePanel` to accept input from a USB card reader.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .USBBox
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: -999em;
    }
</style>
```

When I click an `asp:LinkButton` control that is configured to be an `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` for the update panel the control appears on the page and the CSS class is not applied to the `asp:TextBox` control.

This behavior is displayed in IE7.  It works as expected in FireFox 3.5.7

What would cause this behavior and how do I resolve it

Comment: I went ahead and removed the asp:LinkButton from the page to resolve the issue.  I was burning too many calories trying to resolve this simple issue.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround .. drastic as it may be :)

Comment: @Gaby - I was burning too many calories trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There my be a specificity issue. Try

`input.USBBox{
    position:absolute!important;
    left:-999px!important;
}`

And if it works, back out of the !important tags to see what actually caused the issue.

Also declare display:block; just in case.

Comment: @Christopher - No dice.  Neither suggestion did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
.USBBox
{
    display: none;
}
```

or maybe use a asp:HiddenField instead of a textbox.

Comment: @Kaba - I tried using the `display: none` solution and it does not work because the card reader output the track data into an input control will focus set on it.  The only way I could get it to work was with the current CSS class

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.USBBox
{
    display: block;
    width: 100px; /* or however wide you want it */
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    background: #ff0000; /* visually ensure the class style is being applied, remove it later */
}
```

position should only work on items that are displayed as a block. form items by default are displayed inline.

also just for giggles set the background color just to make sure the input box is taking class.

Comment: @Michael - This did not work either.  It will only read and parse the track data when the display attribute is not explicitly set.

Comment: Is this javascript doing the data tracking or serverside?. do you have an online demo of this?

Is IE in quirks mode or standards mode?

Comment: I currently do not have a place to live test it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the new control comes with multiple classes ?

Because IE is having issues when combining classes on a single element..

Comment: @Not sure, the only class being applied (that I know of) that is being applied to the `asp:Textbox` is the USBBox.

Comment: i do not suppose you have this somewhere live so we can live-test it ?

Comment: I currently do not have a place to live test it.